# Error in setting up Apache Spark on Windows

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a Hortonwork Hadoop cluster installed on my Windows machine (version: 2.6.0.2.2.4.2-0002) and I downloaded the Spark 1.4.0 for hadoop 2.6 and later. I haven't changed any settings in my windows environment. When I run the spark-shell command I get the following error message:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/util/AbstractFileClassLoader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
```

I have the scala installed and I have the SCALA_HOME=c:\scala\bin.

I've seen a set of changes that I need to make (e.g. adding some enviromental variable. etc) here and there but neither looks to be complete and didn't make my spark cluster working. I wonder to now the set of required changes I need to make in order to make my spark cluster up and running.